# FTB Tesseract spits items back

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

First the standard fromt he checklist.
Yes they are the same frequency, yes they are chunk loaded.

I have a quarry with a BC transport pipe (stone) connected to a tesseract that is set to send items only. I have another tesseract with the same frequency set to receive items only. However the sending tesseract does not send anything, the blocks fall out of the pipe right close to the tesseract.

I even tried the dummed down version with just pulling stuff out of a box which works fine but the same problem, as soon as the items go into the tesseract they come right out again and are not being transported.

I also tried just leaving an open pipe as the end... it looks the same. To me that indicates that the tesseract never actually takes the item in. Why?

Comment: What exactly is the receiving Tesseract hooked up to?

Comment: I tried it all wooden transport pipe, stone, gold (all bc pipes), powered and unpowered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you switched the build to use Thermal Expansion [ItemDucts](http://ftbwiki.org/Itemduct), it will surely work, but if you want/must use BC pipes than make sure the receiving tesseract is a normal pipe (wooden is not needed) and it has a valid inventory to go into.

also make certain frequencies are set up correctly. Post a screenshot of both tesseracts gui if you are confused.

Comment: Also note: when using itemducts with a tesseract, the itemduct on the receiving end has to be in "extract" mode. It doesn't require a redstone signal, however.

Comment: I used the itemDucts from TE for the receiveing tesseract. the sending still uses BC pipes and it works fine... just BC on receive doesn't work... wooden or not

Comment: @Killerpixler that's very odd.. BC pipes should work just fine with tesseracts, but if you are happy with using itemducts then yay.

Comment: Well I'm not super happy (need to craft two pipes now... But otherwise I'm happy it's working... It's just so weird... I didn't change anything in the configuration, just used the duct instead of the bc pipe